# React Native Project BUILDS Succesfull(with deprecated warning) and opens in my emulator, but keeps loading forever

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native, android-studio, asyncstorage

I used yarn to install the packages, Im using typescript, my index is JS.
I'm getting a white screen with the load symbol on the emulator..
Thanks for the ones helping

Here's what Im getting:

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag. 
(node:41396) Warning: Accessing non-existent property 'padLevels' of module exports inside circular dependency
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
Jetifier found 1123 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Task :app:installDebug
09:49:22 V/ddms: execute: running am get-config
09:49:22 V/ddms: execute 'am get-config' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
09:49:22 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installing APK 'app-debug.apk' on 'Pixel_2_API_28(AVD) - 9' for app:debug
09:49:22 D/app-debug.apk: Uploading app-debug.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
09:49:22 D/Device: Uploading file onto device 'emulator-5554'
09:49:22 D/ddms: Reading file permision of C:\Users\Daniel\CalcSol\android\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk as: rwx------
09:49:22 V/ddms: execute: running pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
09:49:24 V/ddms: execute 'pm install -r -t "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
09:49:24 V/ddms: execute: returning
09:49:24 V/ddms: execute: running rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"
09:49:24 V/ddms: execute 'rm "/data/local/tmp/app-debug.apk"' on 'emulator-5554' : EOF hit. Read: -1
09:49:24 V/ddms: execute: returning
Installed on 1 device.

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings        

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 29s
141 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 139 up-to-date
info Connecting to the development server...
info Starting the app on "emulator-5554"...
Starting: Intent { cmp=com.calcsol/.MainActivity }'''
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1. Delete node_modules and re-install
2. Go to your android folder and delete the file .idea
3. In Android Studio: file > Invalidate Caches / Restart and select 'Invalidate and Restart'

[image: Android Studio popUp]

Comment: I tried that, reinstalled. I switched to npm also, and still the same. But I believe its something in my code, cuz it works perfectly with other codes